# R help in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: r, jupyter

I'm using [this Jupyter notebook](https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/r-notebook) to work on R... How do I do the equivalent of `?someFun`?

When I run that in the notebook, I get:

```
Warning message in seq_len(head.end.idx):
“first element used of 'length.out' argument”
ERROR while rich displaying an object: Error in seq_len(head.end.idx): argument must be coercible to non-negative integer

Traceback:
1. FUN(X[[i]], ...)
...
```

#### Update

When I execute `docker run jupyter/r-notebook` I notice that it **does** pop up the widget (after throwing the error). Not it isn't a popup window, but a panel at the bottom of the workbook. My notebook is 'Trusted', which I think is significant, but I don't know how to turn it off.

When I execute `docker run -e JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes jupyter/r-notebook` I get the error and the widget **does not** pop up. I'm not sure how to set or inspect the JS trust in that environment. I suspect it's related. I don't see any blocked popups in the browser.

Strange that even when it works (the widget opens at the bottom of the browser) I still get an error in the output.

Answer (score 3):

If you launch like `docker run -p 8888:8888 jupyter/r-notebook` you will get the help page like a widget and a warning in your cell output. Check your browser, maybe is blocking pop-up elements.

[image: r-notebook]

Comment: Thanks for showing me what the widget looks like. I do see this now (i.e. working correctly), but only when **not** setting `JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes`

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem. R after v4.1.1 seem to have problems with `repr_html`.
I fixed the problem by following the quotes.

> This tiny commit solves a long standing problem while trying to read help from inside jupyterlab.
>
> In order not to wait for the PR to be merged, you may just install from @renkun-ken 's fork:
> `devtools::install_github("renkun-ken/repr", ref = "fix-html-filter")`

##### Reference

https://github.com/IRkernel/repr/pull/144#event-5589475824

https://github.com/IRkernel/repr/issues/143

Comment: Thanks. I mentioned this here:
https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/1494

Comment: The PR is now merged and installing repr==1.1.4 resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think error is not related to `?`. This is what I see when I try `?seq`:

[image]

Comment: Yes, `help(seq)` and `?seq` are both a problem. I think it's related to trusted JS execution... I think...